# I need to copy values from a Sharepoint list to another in different site collection. Both site collections are on-premise. Many thanks

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

I need to copy certain fields i.e Title , Description values from a Sharepoint doc library to a List in different site collection. Both site collections are on-premise. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Harry, the solution will ultimately decide on your abilities, the number of rows being copied, and/or access to technology.

- You can export to Excel and copy from Excel into the other list

https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/

- You can write a script in PowerShell or C# to copy over the wanted rows of data

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/copy-list-items-between-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell.html

- You can connect to both list in MS Access and write a query to copy over the data

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-link-or-move-data-to-sharepoint-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-link-to-shared-data-0dadda2d-a795-4489-8098-c741879f4259

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
# Variables 
$Username = "<AdminAccount>" 
$Password = "<Password>" 
$sourceSiteCollection = "<Site1>" 
$targetSiteCollection = "<Site2>" 
$sourceList = "<List1>"
$targetList = "<List2>"

# Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 

# ConnectPnPOnline 
try { 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceSiteCollection -Credentials $PSCredentials
    if (-not (Get-PnPContext)) { 
        Write-Host "Error connecting to SharePoint Online, unable to establish context" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red 
        return 
    }else{
        $items=Get-PnPListItem -List $sourceList
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $targetSiteCollection -Credentials $PSCredentials
        foreach($item in $items){
            Add-PnPListItem -List $targetList -Values @{"Title" = $item["Name"];"<Column1>" = $item["<Column1>"]}
        }
    } 
} catch { 
    Write-Host "Error connecting to SharePoint Online: $_.Exception.Message" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red 
    return 
}
```

Make sure you use the **internal names** of the columns.

Reference: [Add-PnPListItem.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps)